# Why is volatile keyword not needed for thread synchronisation?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, volatile

I am reading that the `volatile` keyword is not suitable for thread synchronisation and in fact it is not needed for these purposes at all.

While I understand that using this keyword is not sufficient, I fail to understand why is it completely unnecessary.

For example, assume we have two threads, thread A that only reads from a shared variable and thread B that only writes to a shared variable. Proper synchronisation by e.g. pthreads mutexes is enforced.

IIUC, without the volatile keyword, the compiler may look at the code of thread A and say: “The variable doesn’t appear to be modified here, but we have lots of reads; let’s read it only once, cache the value and optimise away all subsequent reads.” Also it may look at the code of thread B and say: “We have lots of writes to this variable here, but no reads; so, the written values are not needed and thus let’s optimise away all writes.“

Both optimisations would be incorrect. And <del>both</del> **one** would be prevented by volatile. So, I would likely come to the conclusion that while `volatile` is not enough to synchronise threads, it is still necessary for any variable shared between threads. *(note: I now read that actually it is not required for `volatile` to prevent write elisions; so I am out of ideas how to prevent such incorrect optimisations)*

I understand that I am wrong in here. But why?

Comment: the compiler sees both the reads and the writes, so will not optimize the variable away.   You seem to be mixing compile time visibility  with run time accessing.

Comment: @user3629249: nope, that's not what's happening. those two codes could be in entirely different compilation units.

Comment: The compiler has no clue what external API calls do.  It's only interested in the signature.  Linker similar.

Comment: The volatile keyword only affects what assumptions the optimizer is allowed to make.  Which has nothing to do with threading, if compilers were smart enough to generate thread-safe code then nobody would constantly be asking this question.

Comment: In layman's terms: The compiler is free to rearrange or cache reads and writes (as long as there's no difference in the observable behaviour). The synchronization primitives have some "magic" properties that create barriers, and the compiler is not allowed to move reads and writes through these barriers... (it's a little more complex than that, so for a full explanation, wait for a proper answer).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath,  They may be in different compilation units, but some header file must have an `extern` statement for the variable, so the variable is visible to the compiler.  and the compiler will not optimize out an `extern` referenced variable, because while processing one compilation unit, it does not know what the other compilation unit is doing with that same variable.

Comment: @user3629249: This is all irrelevant, it's *not* how it works. I just tried to give an example so you can get a grasp on why it's a bad idea.

Comment: @sabbahillel That's incorrect. Some of the reads and writes inside the locks can be optimized out if the compiler can prove they're not needed. It may or may not be able to do this, but if it tries to do it, it obviously must do it correctly or it's broken.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath,  Since you seem to know so much, where is your answer that explains how it works

Comment: @user3629249: I know a lot, that's why I know I know so little. Let's leave this to the field experts.

Comment: If all the work occurs within mutex protected blocks, then choosing to read once and cache or write only the final value is perfectly legitimate. Why would this be incorrect? If the mutex is held, no one else is reading or modifying the variables until it is released, so the variable can't be changed by another thread (making read optimizations acceptable) and can't be read by another thread, so the other thread would only see the "before" or "after" state, and it doesn't matter whether intermediate values are written as long as the final value is correct.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The way I was figuring out mutexes was something like that: a pthread_mutex_lock operation is nothing but a call “OS, suspend me now unless no one else holds this mutex” and a pthread_mutex_unlock operation is nothing but a call “OS, you can now wake one thread that waits on this mutex”. And nothing else. So, hardly anything in common with optimisations.

Comment: @gaazkam Hopefully you now see that a platform whose mutexes worked that way would be pretty much unusable, even with `volatile`. The whole point of threads, sharing of memory by default, would be unusable.

Answer (score 9):

> For example, assume we have two threads, thread A that only reads from a shared variable and thread B that only writes to a shared variable. Proper synchronisation by e.g. pthreads mutexes is enforced.
>
> IIUC, without the volatile keyword, the compiler may look at the code of thread A and say: “The variable doesn’t appear to be modified here, but we have lots of reads; let’s read it only once, cache the value and optimise away all subsequent reads.” Also it may look at the code of thread B and say: “We have lots of writes to this variable here, but no reads; so, the written values are not needed and thus let’s optimise away all writes.“

Like most thread synchronization primitives, pthreads mutex operations have [explicitly defined memory visibility semantics](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_11).

Either the platform supports pthreads or it doesn't. If it supports pthreads, it supports pthreads mutexes. Either those optimizations are safe or they aren't. If they're safe, there's no problem. If they're unsafe, then any platform that makes them doesn't support pthreads mutexes.

For example, you say "The variable doesn’t appear to be modified here", but it does -- another thread could modify it there. Unless the compiler can prove its optimization can't break any conforming program, it can't make it. And a conforming program can modify the variable in another thread. Either the compiler supports POSIX threads or it doesn't.

As it happens, most of this happens automatically on most platforms. The compiler is just prevented from having any idea what the mutex operations do internally. Anything another thread could do, the mutex operations themselves could do. So the compiler has to "synchronize" memory before entering and exiting those functions anyway. It can't, for example, keep a value in a register across the call to `pthread_mutex_lock` because for all it knows, `pthread_mutex_lock` accesses that value in memory. Alternatively, if the compiler has special knowledge about the mutex functions, that would include knowing about the invalidity of caching values accessible to other threads across those calls.

A platform that requires `volatile` would be pretty much unusable. You'd need versions of every function or class for the specific cases where an object might be made visible to, or was made visible from, another thread. In many cases, you'd pretty much just have to make everything `volatile` and not caching values in registers is a performance non-starter.

As you've probably heard many times, `volatile`'s semantics as specified in the C language just do not mix usefully with threads. Not only is it not sufficient, it disables many perfectly safe and nearly essential optimizations.

Comment: No offence, but you're addressing him like he's stupid. His question is *wise*, he just doesn't know about those visibility semantics... on which you don't elaborate and all. Focus on what's important.

Comment: Said another way, the compiler is free to make any optimizations it wants within a synchronization block as another thread will only look at the variable outside of this synchronization block (and presumable within it's own).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath He knows `volatile` isn't sufficient. He's asking why it's necessary to tell the compiler not to optimize in code that he knows tells the compiler not to optimize some other way. It's really sufficient to point out that you don't have to tell it twice. It listens the first time. I don't think it's helpful to get bogged down in platform-specific implementation details.

Comment: "*I don't think it's helpful to get bogged down in platform-specific implementation details.*" - I totally agree. Let's give a high level platform-independent view.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath The high-level view is that the platform supports POSIX threads and thus does whatever's necessary to make this work. You don't have to tell the compiler twice, it listens.

Comment: My thinking was that mutexes ensure that accesses do not take place at the same time, which has (relatively) little to do with optimisations, but rather with suspending the execution of a thread whenever it reaches the locking instruction and the mutex happens to be already locked. Thinking about it a little longer, this means that accesses should not be reordered in a certain way, but not that they should not be optimised out

Comment: @DavidSchwartz All that is because most thread function arn't treated as normal functions, but provides certain memory synchronization and visibility guarantees - which isn't necessarily obvious to everyone. (e.g. the list at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_11 for pthreads)

Comment: The way I was figuring out mutexes was something like that: a `pthread_mutex_lock` operation is nothing but a call “OS, suspend me now unless no one else holds this mutex” and a `pthread_mutex_unlock` operation is nothing but a call “OS, you can now wake one thread that waits on this mutex”. And nothing else. So, hardly anything in common with optimisations. I understand I was wrong, thank you for enlightening me

Comment: @gaazkam Ahh, I see now. Sorry, I didn't realize that was the issue.

Comment: That's what I was also trying to tell, but failed. Lol.

Comment: I'd be very suspicious about that. File A provides a library of functions that access variables present in that file, say, a class with its methods and class variables. The compiler has no clue about threads and happily optimizes the use of these variables when compiling these functions, clueless about threads. File B performs calls to these functions from different threads, warding the calls with mutexes. But when it does it, the prior file has long been compiled, its optimizations already made. The two are linked, and there's nothing the linker can do to undo the earlier optimizations.

Comment: @SF. Try to construct this counterexample and you'll find it's not possible. Remember two things: 1) For the code to be legal, it has to use the mutexes correctly when calling the file. 2) The compiler is prevented from seeing into the mutex functions and so has to assume they can call into that file.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Wait, a different counterexample. I make my own wrappers over pthread_mutex_lock() and pthread_mutex_unlock() (a fairly common practice when debugging mutex issues), and they sit in a different compilation unit. Are you sure any variable sitting between two calls of two random functions off the compilation unit will receive "due attention"? `while(1){ my_lock(); if(got_new_data){ got_new_data = 0; send_data(); } my_unlock(); usleep(1); }` ? The compiler has all the reasons to believe `got_new_data` is unaffected - especially if it's a local variable to which pointer I pass out.

Comment: @SF. How does it know that `my_lock` doesn't call into that very function and modify the local variable? Anything another thread could do, your lock/unlock functions could do (assuming they call into the mutex functions).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: It doesn't. It can therefore either be paranoid and optimize nothing at all, because *everything* can be accessed externally and modified on the fly, or it can assume something not explicitly declared as volatile is in fact non-volatile, and happily optimize it away. Or try to make more or less informed, more or less correct guesses. If all calls to any arbitrary functions present outside of current compilation unit were assumed to modify unrelated local variables, no optimization could be done, ever.

Comment: @SF. Everything about what you said is wrong. I don't know how to explain it in the space of a few hundred characters, but it's wrong. The compiler can sometimes tell that a local variable can't be modified and sometimes it can't. When it can, it can optimize it. When it can't, it can't. The use of `volatile` has nothing to do with this at all. You can use locals however you want and a compiler whose optimized broke them would be broken. That includes statics, taking their address, whatever. It's actually not even complicated.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Maybe it changed in recent years. When I was learning this stuff, you either had to be very explicit about which variables are shared between threads, or go with `-O0`, or you'd end up ears deep in hard to diagnose bugs as changes to variables would fail to propagate across threads.

Comment: @SF. That's just a sign of a programmer who doesn't understand threads and/or a bad platform. Both platforms and programmers have matured significantly since then. Yes, there were definitely threads-related compiler bugs and there were definitely platforms with poorly-defined semantics with respect to threads. Fortunately, such voodoo methods are no longer needed. Thankfully, we now have lots of thread synchronization primitives with very precisely defined semantics on all the platforms you're likely to use threads on.

Answer (score 4):

Shortening the answer already given, you do not need to use `volatile` with mutexes for a simple reason:

- If compiler knows what mutex operations are (by recognizing pthread_* functions or because you used `std::mutex`), it well knows how to handle access in regards to optimization (which is even required for `std::mutex`)
- If compiler does not recognize them, pthread_* functions are completely opaque to it, and no optimizations involving any sort of non-local duration objects can go across opaque functions

Comment: I'd very much love to know what's wrong with my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Making the answer even shorter, not using either a mutex or a semaphore, is a bug.  As soon as thread B releases the mutex (and thread A gets it), any value in the register which contains the shared variable's value from thread B are guaranteed to be written to cache or memory that will prevent a race condition when thread A runs and reads this variable.

The implementation to guarantee this is architecture/compiler dependent.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `volatile` tells the compiler to treat any write *or read* of the variable as an "observable side-effect." That is all it does. Observable side-effects of course must not be optimized away, and must appear to the outside world as occurring in the order the program indicates; The compiler may not re-order observable side-effects *with regard to each other.* The compiler is however free to reorder them with respect to non-observables. Therefore, `volatile` is only appropriate for accessing memory-mapped hardware, Unix-style signal handlers and the like.  For inter-thread concurrence, use `std::atomic` or higher level synchronization objects like `mutex`, `condition_variable`, and `promise/future`.