# Stop a thread when an event occurs

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, visual-c++

I want the `main` function to stop `function_` when an event occurs (after 1ms in this example). The problem I have is that `function_` immediately relock the mutex without letting the `main` function to get it.

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

void function_(volatile bool *ptrStop, mutex *ptrMtx) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ptrMtx->lock();
        if (*ptrStop) {
            ptrMtx->unlock();
            return;
        }
        //doSomething();
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1));
        cout << "Iteration " << i << endl;
        ptrMtx->unlock();
        //this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1));
    }
    return;
}


int main() {
    volatile bool stop = 0;
    mutex mtx;

    thread functionThread(function_, &stop, &mtx);

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1));
    mtx.lock();
    stop = 1;
    mtx.unlock();
    cout << "Changed boolean variable value" << endl;
    functionThread.join();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I got the following output :

```
Iteration 0
Iteration 1
Iteration 2
Iteration 3
Iteration 4
Iteration 5
Iteration 6
Iteration 7
Iteration 8
Iteration 9
Changed boolean variable value
```

What I want is to only do 1 or 2 iterations of `function_`only (therefor let the `main` take the mutex). How can I do that ? I heard about the `std::condition_variable` but I couldn't figure a way to make what I want.

Moreover, if `doSomething()` is uncommented and takes a long time to return, is there an easy way to kill the thread or force it to join without modifying what is in `doSomething` function ?

Comment: Can you show what you tried with `std::condition_variable`?  It should be what you want to use.

Comment: Volatile is not intended for multi-threading purposes (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35345899/why-is-volatile-keyword-not-needed-for-thread-synchronisation).

Comment: Right now the thread could complete run all iterations of `function_` before `mtx.lock()` is reached in the main thread.

Comment: Did you read the documentation of `std::condition_variable`? It should be easy to extend the example such that it does what you want. You just need a stop flag and a loop in the worker thread.

Comment: Don't use `lock` and `unlock`. Use either `std::unique_lock` or `std::lock_guard` as appropriate.

Comment: Don't use `volatile`. It does not do what most people think. It is useless for inter-thread communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need all that mechanism.  An `atomic<bool>` and `join` will suffice.

Don't use `lock` and `unlock`.  Use either `unique_lock` or `lock_guard` as appropriate.

Don't use `volatile` unless you are dealing with memory-mapped hardware or unix signal-handlers.

SPOILER ----

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;  // Kids, don't try this at home.

using stopper = atomic<bool>;

void function_( stopper *ptrStop) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (*ptrStop) {
            break;
        }
        //doSomething();
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10));
        cout << "Iteration " << i << endl;
        //this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1));
    }
    *ptrStop = false;
    return;
}


int main() {
    stopper stop{ false };
    thread functionThread(function_, &stop);

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));

    stop = true;
    // // The following is optional
    ///while (stop == true) {
    //    this_thread::yield();
    //}
    cout << "Changed boolean variable value" << endl;
    functionThread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I thought this would have been more compliacted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to answer this question:

> Moreover, if doSomething() is uncommented and takes a long time to
>   return, is there an easy way to kill the thread or force it to join
>   without modifying what is in doSomething function?

The answer is no.  If you try and kill the thread in any way, you can not be sure that it's been killed at a time when it was harmless to other threads to do so.  For example; your c++ library could implement new with a mutex; if you're in the middle of creating a new object when your thread is killed; the mutex will remain locked for ever; leaving all other threads unable to call new.  This will result in your program deadlocking in a way that you'll never be able to debug.

The only way you can do this reliably is do a little work in `doSomething()`; and then check to see if you can go back and do more.